# NSInternalInconsistencyException error from collectionView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

Hi I have two different cell(it may be 6-7 in the future) I return them by some case in cellForItem method of collection view but I got this error(the cell returned from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: does not have a reuseIdentifier - cells must be retrieved by calling)

Here is my codes.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let idx = viewModel?.component?.firstIndex(where: { $0.type == .summary }) {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: SummaryCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? SummaryCollectionViewCell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
        if let summaryData = viewModel?.component?[idx].dataModel as? SummaryData {
            let summaryViewModel = SummaryCollectionViewCellViewModel(summaryData: summaryData)
            cell.configure(with: summaryViewModel)
        }
    } else if let idx = viewModel?.component?.firstIndex(where: { $0.type == .merchant }) {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MerchantCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? MerchantCollectionViewCell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
        if let merchantData = viewModel?.component?[idx].dataModel as? MerchantData {
            let merchantViewModel = MerchantCollectionViewCellViewModel(merchantData: merchantData)
            cell.configure(with: merchantViewModel)
        }
    }
    
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is legal to *say*

```
return UICollectionViewCell()
```

in order to quiet the compiler, but it is *illegal* to *execute* it. You are executing it, because neither wing of your condition is *returning a cell*.

You are saying `let cell =` in both wings, but then you just throw `cell` away! You never say `return cell`. You must dequeue a cell, configure it, *and return it*. Do not return some other cell; return the cell you dequeued and configured, namely `cell`.

Comment: oh I forgot return cell after configure methods sorry now I put return cell and it's work thank you.

Comment: but now only my cell named SummaryCollectionViewCellView is returning I want one of both to appear

Comment: That's a different issue. Ask a new question with your new code. But I notice that you never examine `indexPath` so why would the first `if` ever fail?